# What is int foo[] = {1200,100} and how do I recreate it in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

Testing out some third party objective-C code I see the following:

```
int beepData[] = {1200,100};
```

What am I looking at here? An int is being created from a pair of other integers? I've not seen this feature before.

I would also like to know how to create the same variable in Swift.

EDIT

I assumed this was returning an int, not an array. The code I'm reviewing looks like this:

```
int beepData[] = {1200,100};
[[DTDevices sharedDevice] barcodeSetScanBeep:TRUE volume:10 beepData:beepData length:sizeof(beepData) error:nil];
```

Where the method signature I am intending to pass the variable to is:

```
-(BOOL)barcodeSetScanBeep:(BOOL)enabled volume:(int)volume beepData:(int *)data length:(int)length error:(NSError **)error;
```

I guess the right question might have been - what is (int *) and how might I create one in Swift?

Comment: Its an integer array of two elements. Initialized to that values.

Comment: That's called an array.

Comment: But the resulting type is declared as an int

Comment: And the empty brackets tell the compiler to determine the size by looking at the number of elements in the initializer list

Comment: It is declared as `int[]`, not `int`.

Comment: @BenPackard , In C, arrays aren't declared as `int[] beepData = {1200,100};`. They are declared as `int beepData[] = {1200,100};`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not in the working code I'm looking at. That's the confusion.

Comment: @BenPackard Is the code I am looking at is different from that you are looking at?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Does int beepData[] declare an int or an array of ints? I guess the confusion is that as an objective-c user this looks like an int is being created, not an array.

Comment: It's C syntax for declaring arrays. If you are not familiar with it, you should take a look at the docs.

Comment: @BenPackard , It declares an array of `int`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c?lq=1)

Comment: C declarations are designed so that they mimic their usage in code. i.e. `int beepData[]` says "`beepData[]` is an `int`", therefore `beepData` is an `int` array. Yes, it's odd. On the other hand, having used C and C++ for many years, I tend to screw up array declarations in more modern languages even though the syntax makes more sense simply because my fingers insist on typing them the C way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I looking at here?

That is an array of ints, with two elements.

---

> [How can I] create the same variable in Swift?

The same variable in swift might be declared as:

```
var beepData : [Int] = [ 1200, 100 ]
```

You might find this answer about [different ways to declare an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/916299) useful

---

> What is `(int *)`

It's an `int pointer`, it points to the memory address of an int. Incrementing it would move along the memory addresses (in int-sized chunks) and point to the next bit of memory.

```
[1][3][5][4][2]
 ^
```

This little arrow represents an `int*`. Even though it currently points to 1,
incrementing it doesn't equal 2. In this case it would equal 3, the value of the int in the next block of memory.

```
[1][3][5][4][2]
    ^
```

---

> How might I create one in Swift?

To be quite honest, I'm not sure if Swift has pointers in the normal sense. I've not used it a great deal. However, if you are porting that method, I'd probably give it an array of ints.

```
func barcodeSetScanBeep(enabled : Bool, volume : Int, beepData: [Int], length : Int, error : NSError)
```

Comment: But the result is assigned to an int - that's what's confusing me.

Comment: Is your confusion simply because the `[]` isn't directly next to `int`?

Comment: Partly, yes - so the returned type here is an array, not an Int? The other confusing part is that this value is successfully passed to another method that accepts an Int.

Comment: I don't think so. Show that method call

Comment: @BenPackard perhaps you had better post the code for what you are trying to describe now about passing to a function. If the argument is `int *arg` then that arg can point to a single `int` or to an array of `int`s.

Comment: @BenPackard , Yes. That is because the name of the array "decays"(gets converted) into a pointer that points to the address of the first element of the array(an `int*`). Note that I'm talking about C here. No idea about objective-C and swift

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just thought that, perhaps they just don't like me :P I can't see anything wrong with the answer though. Can you?

Comment: I have no Idea what Swift is, but it looks like an answer to both parts of the question..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Swift won't allow type [Int] for an expected parameter type of (int *) so this won't compile. Swift is Apple's new programming language for iOS and OS X.

Comment: I think this answers the question I asked, but unfortunately [Int] isn't accepted in the message call. I'm not porting, but consuming - Swift is compatible with objective-C. I think I should ask a better question now I know what I am looking at.

Answer (score 1):

That's a **C array**, declared with `1200` and `100` as the members of the array.
Its declared with the type, and a bracket with the size (or empty for compiler deduced size), such as `int cArrayOfInts[] = blahblahblah`.

Note how the members of the array can be primitives, instead of objects. This isn't possible in Objective-C.

To recreate this in swift, simply use `var beepData = [1200, 100]` and it will be type inferred to an array of `Int`s.

Comment: I find your statement about Objective-C not supporting good-old C arrays quite surprising. Can you back that up? Or are you saying NSArray doesn't support primitive types?

Comment: var beepData = [1200, 100] is not a valid type when the method expects (int *)

Answer (score 0):

James already answered the particulars of your question - consider this some additional information.

Declarations in C are based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.  If you have an array of integers and you want to access the `i`'th integer, you would write

```
x = arr[i];
```

The type of the *expression* `arr[i]` is `int`, so the declaration of `arr` is written as

```
int arr[N]; // arr is an N-element array of int
```

Similar logic applies to pointer declarations; if you have a pointer to a `double` and you want to access the pointed-to value, you'd write

```
y = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `double`, so the declaration of `p` is written as

```
double *p;
```

Same for function declarations; you call a function that returns an integer as

```
x = f();
```

The type of the expression `f()` is `int`, so the declaration of the function is written as

```
int f( void ); // void means the function takes no parameters
```

C declaration syntax uses something called a *declarator* to specify an object's array-ness, pointer-ness, or function-ness.  For example:

```
int x, arr[10], *p, f(void);
```

declares `x` as a plain `int`, `arr` as a 10-element array of `int`, `p` as a pointer to an `int`, and `f` as function taking no parameters and returning `int`.

You'll occasionally see pointer declarations written as `T* p`, however they will be parsed as `T (*p)`; the `*` is always part of the declarator, not the type specifier.

C declaration syntax allows you to create some pretty complex types in a compact format, such as

```
int *(*(*f[N])(void))[M];
```

In this declaration, `f` is an N-element array of pointers to functions returning pointers to M-element arrays of pointers to `int`.

In your declaration

```
int beepData[] = {1200, 100};
```

`beepData` is being declared as an array of an unknown size; the size is taken from the number of elements in the initializer `{1200, 100}`, in this case 2.

I know nothing about Swift, so I wouldn't know how to translate the C code to it.  The best I can do is explain how the C code works.